# Display the 4th icon after 3 icons in header

Tags: magento

we are trying to add 4th icon after 3 icons in header.

[image]

but whereever i placed below code in header.phtml , its not working.

4th icon is displaying before 3 icons. i want to display after 3 icons.

**code for 4th icon.**

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/search_16.png');?>" alt="Search">
```

**header.phtml**

```
<div id="header">
<header id="header" class="page-header">
    <div class="page-header-container">
        <a class="logo" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="large" />
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrcSmall() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="small" />
        </a>

        <div id='hideshow'><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/search_16.png');?>" alt="Search"></div>

        <?php // In order for the language switcher to display next to logo on smaller viewports, it will be moved here.
              // See app.js for details ?>
        <div class="store-language-container"></div>

        <!-- Skip Links -->

        <div class="skip-links">
            <a href="#header-nav" class="skip-link skip-nav">
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Menu'); ?></span>
            </a>

            <a href="#header-search" class="skip-link skip-search" id="hideshow1">
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Search'); ?></span>
            </a>

            <div class="account-cart-wrapper">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('customer')->getAccountUrl(); ?>" data-target-element="#header-account" class="skip-link skip-account">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <!-- <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Account'); ?></span> -->
                </a>


                <!-- Cart -->

                <div class="header-minicart">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart_head'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <!-- Navigation -->

        <div id="header-nav" class="skip-content">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
        </div>

        <!-- Search -->

        <div id="header-search" class="skip-content desktop-only">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        </div>

        <!-- Account -->

        <div id="header-account" class="skip-content">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!--<div id="header-search" class="desktop-only">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        </div>-->
</header>


<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the style set to those img tags ( or wrapping div or any element ) as follows

```
float : right;
```

If so, add the 4th icon as the 1st item. Then it will display at the end ( after 3 images )

Comment: there is no something like that, can you please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269248/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center)

Comment: URL is for another stackoverflow question. Please verify